# Just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04. Where is the desktop?

Tags: boot

I just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04. Where is the desktop. I have been having trouble with all these distros; they come with no
 desktop and no terminal. How can you run the program??

Comment: Did you download from the [official site for Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)? If yes everything should be ok. (I did that 3 weeks ago).

Comment: Please be more specific on what you've tried, and what the result was.  For example, you downloaded what?  The ISO?  Did you boot into the ISO from a USB or CD/DVD?

Comment: All Ubuntu flavors include a Terminal. All Ubuntu flavors (except Ubuntu Server) include a desktop.

Comment: @William400, please mark an anwser.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused about Ubuntu and other GNU/Linux distros.

**Ubuntu is not a program, it's an operating system like Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X.**

**--> You need to burn a CD/DVD or USB drive with the ISO file that you downloaded.**

Then, reboot the computer, boot from the disk (or USB) and try it or install it from there.

**If you choose to install, you will most likely lose *everything* on your hard drive, make sure to try the system first before installing.**